# How to access a thread defined in another class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have encountered a problem when I want to do a time counting.
Basicly the problem is like this: there is a class A, which initiates a private thread in itself, and I have a instant of A in my class B, and in the main method of B I invoked some methods of A and want to test the time to run these methods.

```
A a = new A();
//start time counter
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ invoke a.method() that takes some time}
//end time counter and prints the time elapsed
```

but by doing so the method in the for loop will running in a seperate thread in A and the prints method in the last line would probably be executed before the loop ends. So I want to access the thead in a and invokes a join() to wait until all stuff in the for loop get finished. Could you help me figure how to achieve this? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I want to try Thread.currentThread(), but the A class is a third party class that could not be modified.

Comment: Is it possible that `A` exposes some threading functionality in its public interface ? I'm thinking of allowing you to `join()` its inner thread, for instance (without actually exposing its thread reference). Or does it perform some `notify()` on the `A` instance when finished (so that you can `wait()` on it) ?

Comment: Hi Costi, in fact A is the AsyncAppender in log4j, and I configure it in a .xml file, all I have in my program is a Logger that has already append that appender a. I do not have access to any reference to the appender itself. Even though I can get one reference by invoking getAppender() on the Logger, there is no public interface availabel for the appender to access the thread. Any way thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**List All Threads and their Groups**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void visit(final ThreadGroup group, final int level)
    {
        final Thread[] threads = new Thread[group.activeCount() * 2];
        final int numThreads = group.enumerate(threads, false);

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            Thread thread = threads[i];
            System.out.format("%s:%s\n", group.getName(), thread.getName());
        }

        final ThreadGroup[] groups = new ThreadGroup[group.activeGroupCount() * 2];
        final int numGroups = group.enumerate(groups, false);

        for (int i = 0; i < numGroups; i++)
        {
            visit(groups[i], level + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        ThreadGroup root = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().getParent();
        while (root.getParent() != null)
        {
            root = root.getParent();
        }

        visit(root, 0);
    }
}
```

Based on your edits, you might can find out what group and name the thread is and get a reference to it that way and do what you need to do.

**For your own code in the future**

You want to look at [ExecutorCompletionService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) and the other thread management facilities in [java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). You should not be managing threads manually in Java anymore, pretty much every case you can imagine is handled one or more of the [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) implementations.

Comment: I had found this piece of code somewhere else, it solves my question, thank you Jarrod.